# ¿Como evitar que los divs se desplacen al redimensionar el alto de mi pantalla?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```css
.contenedor{
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    
}

.telefono{
    background-color: #AD7D27;   
    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #42300F;
   
}

/*MENU NAVEGACION*/
nav{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #42300F;
    
}

.navegacion a{
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
    color: #42300F;
}

.iconos li a{
    color: #AD7D27
}

.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;    
   
}

/*FIN MENU NAVEGACION*/

.slider1{
    height: 84.5vh;
    background-image: url(img/FACU.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;/*para que nuestra imagen de fondo no se repita*/
    background-size: cover; /*para que nuestra imagen de fondo esté centrada*/
}


.slider2{
    height: 84.5vh;
    background-image: url(img/combi.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;/*para que nuestra imagen de fondo no se repita*/
    background-size: cover; /*para que nuestra imagen de fondo esté centrada*/
}
.slider3{
    height: 84.5vh;
    background-image: url(img/tekilaso.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;/*para que nuestra imagen de fondo no se repita*/
    background-size: cover; /*para que nuestra imagen de fondo esté centrada*/
}

/*FIN HEADER*/

.logo{
    height: 100vh;  
    color: #5C4315;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
/********************************************/

.desafiamos h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.primero{
    background-color: #AD7D27;   
}

.parrafo{
    font-size: 1.1rem;  
}

/*.oldSchool{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(img/old-school.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;/*para que nuestra imagen de fondo no se repita*/
   /* background-size: cover; /*para que nuestra imagen de fondo esté centrada*/
/*}

/**************************************************/

.reservas{
    height: 100vh; 
 }

/****************************************************/

section .galeria{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:  #AD7D27; 
    color: #42300F;

}

.footer{    
    color: #5C4315;
    font-size: 1rem;   
}
```

```html
<body>
        <section class="contenedor">

            <!--PORTADA-->
            <header class="portada">  

                <!--TELEFONO / CORREO-->  
                <section class="container-fluid telefono text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col py-2">
                        Cel: 3794347949 | sebastianpersoglia@gmail.com 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section><!--TELEFONO / CORREO-->  
                        
                <!--MENU NAVEGACION-->  
                <section class="barra">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logos/Isologo.png" width="40" height="40" alt=""></a>
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                                <div class="navbar-nav m-auto navegacion">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#logo">conocenos</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#reservas">reservas</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#galeria">galeria</a>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </nav>
                </section>
                <!--MENU NAVEGACION-->  

                <!--SLIDER-->    
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide d-none d-sm-block" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                      
                        <div class="carousel-inner">  
                            <div class="carousel-item active slider1">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h1></h1>
                                    <p></p>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item slider2">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h1></h1>
                                    <p></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item slider3">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h1></h1>
                                    <p></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div><!--SLIDER-->

                <!--SLIDER2-->
                <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade d-sm-none" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="img/FACU2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="img/milto2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="img/juansa.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </div> <!--SLIDER2-->

            </header><!--PORTADA-->
                 
            <!--LOGO-->
            <section class="container-fluid pt-5 bg-light">
                    <div class="row logo align-items-center justify-content-center text-center" id="logo">
                        
                        <div class="col-8">
                          <img class="img-fluid pb-5 h-100" src="img/logos/logo3.png" alt="" width="500">
                            <div>No somos una barra movil, somos un bar en tu evento.</div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
            </section><!--LOGO-->
               
            <!--DESAFIAMOS-->
            <article class="desafiamos bg-dark" id="desafiamos">         
                    <div class="row no-gutters primero align-items-center text-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 my-5">
                            <h1>DESAFIAMOS LA</h1>
                            <h1>COCTELERIA</h1>
                            <p class="parrafo px-5 mx-5 pt-5">El servicio de DREAM DRINKS BAR, es por excelencia un servicio "PREMIUM" de barras móviles. Lo verá representado en el modo en que trabajamos.</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/old-school.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </article>

            <section class="segundo bg-light  d-none d-lg-block">
                <div class="row no-gutters ">
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/cynaraso.jpeg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 ">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/maracuya.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 ">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/pepe.JPG" alt="">   
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 ">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/sour.jpeg" alt="">
                    </div>
            </div>
            </section><!--DESAFIAMOS-->

            <!--FORMULARIO-->
            <section class="container-fluid" >
                    <div class="row quesomos reservas justify-content-center align-items-center bg-light text-center" id="reservas">
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8"> 
                            <h2 class="pt-5">...Consultanos por reservas, </h2><h2>contactate con nosotros!!</h2>
                            <!--FORMULARIO-->
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="col-8 pb-5 mb-5">   
                                        <form class="">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="email" class="col-form-label color">Dejanos tu Correo!</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"  required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="mensaje" class="col-form-label color">Te leemos:</label>
                                                <textarea rows="3" name="mensaje" class="form-control" id="mensaje" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="boton1 btn btn-outline-warning" id="btnLimpiar">Enviar></button>                 
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--FORMULARIO-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
            </section><!--FORMULARIO-->
            
           <!--GALERIA-->
            <section class="container-fluid galeria text-center d-none d-lg-block" id="galeria">
                    <h2 class=" pt-4">DISFRUTÁ DE NUESTRA GALERIA</h2>
                    
                    <div class="row no-gutters m-auto container">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/brindis.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/brindis.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/brindis2.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/brindis2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/chitaco.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/chitaco.jpeg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/vintage.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/vintage.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/gente.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/gente.jpeg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/pizarra.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/pizarra.jpeg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                
                    </div>
                    <div class="row no-gutters m-auto container">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/vintage3.JPG" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/vintage3.JPG" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/combi.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/combi.jpeg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/sky.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/sky.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/valdeCoca.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/valdeCoca.jpeg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/gente1.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/gente1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/juansa1.png" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/juansa1.png" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="row no-gutters m-auto container">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/milton1.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/milton1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/negroni.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/negroni.jpeg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/trago.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/trago.jpeg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/vintage2.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/vintage2.jpeg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/trago3.JPG" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/trago3.JPG" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="img/galeria/juansa.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/juansa.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            
                    </div>
                        
            </section><!--GALERIA-->
           
            <!--FOOTER-->
            <section class="footer text-center bg-light py-2">
                <footer class=" px-3">© 2019 - Dream Drinks Bar | Diseño y desarrollo by Sebastian Persoglia - Juan Persoglia</footer> 
            </section><!--FOOTER-->
        
       

            
            
    
    

        </section>
        
        

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

escribo para hacer una consulta. Me estoy iniciando en el desarrollo web con el uso principalmente de BOOTSTRAP para el maquetado y un poco de jquery para animaciones, plugings etc.

El problema que estoy teniendo lo pueden ver en la imagen que voy a adjuntar. Los divs de mi web en la cual estoy trabajando se superponen sobre otros cuando disminuyo el alto de mi navegador. Podrian ayudarme a solucioanar, desde ya gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu codigò para verificar que es lo que puede ser ?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! muestra tu html y css de ser necesario para ver que puede estar provocando eso

Comment: Si estas mencionando que reduciendo el tamaño de tu pantalla a determinado nivel en pixeles, es claro que el contenido se ira adaptando para no generar scroll, se conoce como responsive.

Comment: ahí cargué mis archivos, desde ya les pido disculpas si son pocos entendibles. Como aclaré antes, me estoy iniciando y trato de ser lo mas ordenado posible. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas trabajando con bootstrap ten en cuenta el sistema de rejillas, este sistema de rejillas permite que puedas diseñar una pagina responsive. Ahora, para que tus elementos entren (por decirlo de alguna manera) al sistema de rejillas, debes encerrarlos en un contenedor, es alli donde bootstrap te facilita organizar tus elementos. Cala linea en el sistema de rejillas tiene 12 columnas o espacios, se configura esto usando la clase .col-...
Ejemplo si quiero que en una linea un elemento quede al lado de otro uso la clase .col-6 en cada uno, 6 + 6 = 12 espacios. Puedes ver mas de eso en la documentación de bootstrap.

Trata de encerrar tus elementos en un div  y le colocas a ese la clase .container
debajo de ese colocas otro div con clase .row. No coloques .container y .row en el mismo div.

Aparte en ese section de galeria tienes  y justo debajo tienes otro div con .container, si ya encerraste todo en un contenedor no tienes porque declararlo de nuevo, con un contenedor basta para que section sea responsive. Luego de arreglar eso aplica 100vh. Aqui te dejo una sugerencia de como podes hacerlo.

```
<section class="container-fluid text-center d-none d-lg-block" id="galeria">
    <h2 class=" pt-4">DISFRUTÁ DE NUESTRA GALERIA</h2>

    <div class="row no-gutters m-auto">
        <div class="galeria">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                    <a href="img/galeria/brindis.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/brindis.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                    <a href="img/galeria/brindis2.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/brindis2.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                    <a href="img/galeria/chitaco.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/chitaco.jpeg" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                    <a href="img/galeria/vintage.jpg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/vintage.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                    <a href="img/galeria/gente.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/gente.jpeg" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
                    <a href="img/galeria/pizarra.jpeg" data-lightbox="galeria">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/galeria/miniaturas/pizarra.jpeg" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tu codigo y sugerencia me ayudo mucho realmente, ordené muchisimo mi codigo y es mucho mas entendible, aun así, sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Descubrí que quitando la propiedad "height: 100vh;" del CSS ya no se superponen mas los divs. Mi inconveniente es como logro ahora que esos divs tengan el alto total de la pantalla?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPersoglia para lograr lo que quieres puedes usar secciones con un `height: 100vh;`

Comment: @JheymanMejia si, el problema es que cuendo uso esa propiedad, se vuelven a amontonar los divs

Comment: A ver, añade {min-height: 100vh; height: 100%; display: table;} al elemento a ver

Comment: Voy a actualizar mi respuesta para qeu veas, ademas te voy a explicar otra cosa porque tienes un contenedor dentro de otro contenedor en el section de galeria

Comment: @henryscode Me diste la solucion! eh aplicado las propiedades que me diste y funciona muy bien sin que se superpongan los divs! MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Que bueno men, estamos para servir, exito en tu proyecto.

Comment: @henryscode muchas gracias. No estaba teniendo en cuenta el min-height: 100vh; con eso ya solucioné, nuevamente gracias.